# Linear Partial Differential Equations second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

My general solution to the question below is

$U(x,y)=F\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+G(xy)$,  Can someone please confirm this for me? I thought id differentiated the solution correctly and works when put in original equation but not $100\%$ sure. Thanks.

Consider the linear second order equation 
$$ x^2U_{xx} −y^2U_{yy} =0, \qquad\qquad $$

in the region $V =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :x>0,y>0\}$.

(a) Determine the type of the above equation in region V  .

(b) Reduce equation to the corresponding canonical form by making a suitable change of independent variables.

(c) Obtain the general solution of equation

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: No, it is not correct. 
\begin{align}
u_{xx} &= \frac{1}{y^{2}} F'' + y^{2} G'' \\
u_{yy} &= \frac{-2x}{y^{3}} F' + \frac{x^{2}}{y^{4}} F'' + x^{2} G'' \\
\implies x^{2} u_{xx} - y^{2} u_{yy} &= \frac{2x}{y} F''
\end{align}

Comment: However, if $F \equiv 0$...